# Stored procedure to Update table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm using a stored procedure to insert record and into two tables but it is only inserting in one table at the moment. In debugging it doesn't go the try area in order to store the data in the other table. These are are the two stored procedure as well as the method used to call the stored procedures

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createRequestedItem] 
    @expense_acc varchar(50),
    @quantity_requested int,
    @inventory_acc varchar(50),
    @Req_No varchar(50),
    @Item_No varchar (50),
    @unit_of_measure varchar(15), 
    @issue_price float
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO RequisitionItem 
    VALUES (@expense_acc, @quantity_requested, @inventory_acc, @Req_No, @Item_No,
            @unit_of_measure, @issue_price)
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[requisition_sp_createRequisition]
    @Req_No varchar(50),    
    @Req_Date datetime,
    --@description varchar (50),
    --@quantity int,
    @employee_id nvarchar (50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Requisition 
    VALUES (@Req_No, @Req_Date, 
            --@description,
            --@quantity,
            @employee_id)
END
```

Model class:

```
  public bool createRequisition(Requisition requisition, Item requisitionitem)
  {
        int rec_upd = 0;
        bool status;

        using (SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCommand requestcommand = new SqlCommand();

            //Command to update the requisition table with the header information
            requestcommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
            requestcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            requestcommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_createRequisition";

            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = requisition.reqDate;

            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@employee_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.employeeDetails.employeeNum;

            //Command to update the issueitem table with details of the transaction
            command.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "createRequestedItem";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Req_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
            command.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = requisition.inventory_account;
            command.Parameters.Add("@item_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@quantity_requested", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Parameters.Add("@issue_price", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Parameters.Add("@expense_acc", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@unit_of_measure", SqlDbType.VarChar);

            try
            {
                TWCLOPConnect.Open();
                requestcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                foreach (var item in requisition.items)
                {
                    command.Parameters["@itemnum"].Value = item.itemNumber;
                    command.Parameters["@issue_price"].Value = item.price;
                    command.Parameters["@qty"].Value = item.quantity;
                    command.Parameters["@expense_acc"].Value = item.expense_account.index;
                    command.Parameters["@unit_of_measure"].Value = item.selecteduomtext.Trim();

                    rec_upd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                TWCLOPConnect.Close();
            }

            if (rec_upd > 0)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }

        return status;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the "@itemnum" and "@qty" parameters added to command. You are trying to set their values but they are not defined, right?

Comment: Yeah but after making those changes you pointed; i'm still able to set their values

Comment: I think it's not clear what happens there. You are saying your code is not reaching the try block? You can debug until reaching the try statement?

Comment: yeah when it reaches the try block, it jumps out of the function

Comment: On the try statement? That's quite unlikely. Or on the Connection.Open() command? You are in Debug mode, right?

Comment: it doesn't go in the try at all